# vb.net, option strict, enums and overriding ToString

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, enums

I have the following code:

```
Public Enum Country
   Canada = 1
   USA = 2
End Enum
```

When I want to see if the user has selected a value, I do:

```
ddl.SelectedValue = Country.Canada
```

Which works fine.  However, if I turn on a warning for implicit conversion, this gives a warning.  Changing it to

```
ddl.SelectedValue = Country.Canada.ToString()
```

fails, since the ToString() method returns "Canada" not "1".

What's the best way to get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly cast the SelectedValue to an int, or the Country as a string.

```
If CInt(ddl.SelectedValue) = Country.Canada
```

or

```
If ddl.SelectedValue = CStr(Country.Canada)
```

If you take the first option, you might need to explicitly declare your enum as Integer

```
Public Enum Country As Integer
```

The warning occurs because SelectedValue is a string, and Country is an Integer, so an implicit conversion occurs - just like it says!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value '1' rather than 'Canada', you can *explicitly* cast it as an integer first, and then call .ToString() on the result of that.

```
ddl.SelectedValue = DirectCast(Country.Canada, Integer).ToString()
```